# locationManager in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to get location from BroadcastReceiver.

I had this in my service and it worked well.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

But now I want to use it in BroadcastReceiver. How should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get location from BroadcastReceiver.

That is unlikely to work well, other than `getLastKnownLocation()`, which can easily return `null`. For anything else, you need a longer-lived component, one that can stick around long enough for the location fix to be obtained. If you want to have finding the location be *triggered* by a broadcast, that is fine, but you probably need a `Service` to actually get the location fix and do something with it.

> I had this in my service and it worked well.

Please remove the call to `getBaseContext()`. You do not need it, and I rather doubt that you know what it does. Call `getSystemService()` on the `Service` itself.

> But now I want to use it in BroadcastReceiver. How should I change it?

If you want to call `getLastKnownLocation()` on a `LocationManager`, you can call `getSystemService()` on a `Context`. You are passed in a `Context` into your `onReceive()` method of your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: I am trying to get GPS location. I had my code in service and it worked well but I want to get my location even when phone is locked thats why I choosed BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @BohumilKulhanek: Getting the location while the device is locked has nothing to do with whether you use a `BroadcastReceiver` or a `Service` to get the location fix.